# What is the best way of determining if a shell script is running on a Google Cloud Compute Engine instance?

Tags: shell, google-compute-engine

I need a shell script to behave slightly differently when running on debian instances provided by different cloud providers.

I can determine if the script is running on EC2 by using:

```
head -c 3 /sys/hypervisor/uuid
```

which will return "ec2" if it is.

What is the equivalent to this that I could use to tell if the script is running on a Google Cloud Compute Engine instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of methods you can use to discover if your script is running within a Google Compute Engine instance.

Firstly, if your script queries the metadata server from a GCE instance, any response will contain the ‘Metadata-Flavor: Google’ header. For example, running `curl metadata.google.internal -i`  would generate an output such as:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Metadata-Flavor: Google 
Content-Type: application/text 
Date: Tue, 07 Nov 2017 16:33:41 GMT 
Server: Metadata Server for VM 
Content-Length: 22 
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block 
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN 0.1/ computeMetadata/
```

You can also use the dmidecode tool to access DMI/SMBIOS information in /proc/mem, which allows you to search for a GCE specific string.

For example, if the following command is run from a GCE instance:

```
sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name | grep "Google Compute Engine"
```

This would generate the following output, which would confirm your command is executing from a GCE instance:

```
Google Compute Engine
```